# Speeding up reactjs complex list rendering

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to speed up the rendering (or perceived rendering) of a very detailed infinite list:

[image: infinite list loading slowly]

I'm rendering the list using reactjs. As you can see certain rows are more detailed than others and when there are a lot of components in the row being rendered, it takes longer.

After profiling the app while scrolling, I've confirmed that the component that takes the longest to render (and thus causes the scrolling to lag) is this one:
[image: component that slows everything down]

I was wondering if there is an easy way with reactjs to render a placeholder there initially, and then only after scrolling has stopped, render the actual costly component.

Or if someone knows of a better way to render detailed infinite lists in a performant way, I'd love to hear. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the "react-infinite" and "react-list" libraries.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I am already using react-list